# Is this limit possible with L'Hospital rule? If so, how do I start it?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} 5 x \tan{\frac{3}{x}}
$$

I have found out a way to prove L'Hospital's rule with the evaluation in this form: 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{5x}{\frac{1}{\tan{\frac{3}{x}}}}
$$
or
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\tan{\frac{3}{x}}}{\frac{1}{5x}}
$$
after this point I am confused on which to choose.

Comment: Yes, it can be done this way. Just continue, it seems like you haven't finished.. find the derivative of the numerator/ denominator etc It's probably easier with $\tan$ in the numerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a change of variables to make things easier

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+}{5\tan(3y)\over y}$$

apply L'Hôpital:

$$=\lim_{y\to 0^+}{15\sec^2(3y)\over 1}=15$$

Comment: Can you show me how you got $\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{5\tan(3u)}{u}$?

Comment: Never mind, I see how to get it now.

Answer (score 3):

L'Hospital is not necessary. Simply write

$$5x\tan(3/x)=15\sec\frac3x\cdot\frac{\sin\frac3x}{\frac3x}$$

Comment: Nice hint. +1${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The original problem ask to use it if we can. I probably should have added that from the start...

Comment: @CameronWetzel Can't hurt to think outside the box though.

Answer (score 1):

$$5x\tan\frac3x=5x\cfrac{\sin\frac3x}{\cos\frac3x}$$

$$=15\sec\frac3x\left(\cfrac{\sin\frac3x}{\frac3x}\right)$$

Now there isn't even any need for L'Hospital.

Comment: Nice hint +1${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $u = 1/x$ The limit will become
$5\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\tan(3u)}{u}$ now use L'Hospital.

Comment: Can you show me how you got $5\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\tan{3u}}{u}$?